# Is there a python function to sort characters in a string

Tags: python

The code is supposed to get a string like 1+1+3+1+3 and sort it and print 1+1+1+3+3

the problem is when I run the code there are lots of '+' in output

wrong output ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++1+1+1+3+3

```
a= input()
b=[]

for i in a:
    if i != '+':
          b.append(i)
for letter in b:
     b='+'.join(sorted(b))     
print(b)
```

Comment: You need to rephrase the title of your question to match the problem. Your problem is not sorting the characters of a string, because that is exactly what `"".join(sorted(some_string))` does.

Comment: Just the second loop is completely unnecessary, you’re not even using `letter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're joining on '+' for every letter in b. So the sorted array is initially:

`['1', '1', '1', '3', '3']`

Then you run a .join('+') for each letter on the re-sorted list, so for the next iterations, this becomes:

```
>>> b='+'.join(sorted(b))
>>> b
'1+1+1+3+3'
>>> b='+'.join(sorted(b))
>>> b
'++++++++1+1+1+3+3'
>>> b='+'.join(sorted(b))
>>> b
'++++++++++++++++++++++++1+1+1+3+3'
```

And so on, because the '+' signs are being added to b, and you are redefining b in every loop iteration.

As other answers have stated, you don't need the second loop, you can just use the following (provided that you're just working with single digits, as in your example)
`b='+'.join(sorted(b))`

For numbers greater than single digits, you might want to rethink how you're parsing the numbers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Try with an input string of '3+20' and see what happens

Comment: As mentioned, it obviously won't work for more than single digits, the question seemed to be more related to why there are + signs in the output, given the approach that the OP is using, which is what I explained.

Answer (score 1):

Start by splitting your string on '+'. Convert each item in the resulting list to int during the sort. Re-join

```
s = '1+1+3+1+3'

print('+'.join(sorted(s.split('+'), key=int)))
```

**Output:**

```
1+1+1+3+3
```

**Note:**

If the numbers in the string are all single-digit then you don't need the *key* parameter therefore:

```
print('+'.join(sorted(s.split('+'))))
```

...will suffice as the sort will be lexicographical

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second for loop.

```
a = input()
b = []

for i in a:
    if i != '+':
        b.append(i)

b = '+'.join(sorted(b))
print(b)
```

Comment: This works with OP's sample data but is not a general solution because it assumes the numbers are all single-digit